# get last item in firebase array

Tags: php, firebase

I'm using the Firebase PHP library and I'd like to get the last item in the array.

I tried:

```
$todoPath = 'arcade/bonsai/gameInPlay/'.$userID.'/'.$gameID.'/'.$gamePlayID.'/scores/';
$response =$fb->get($todoPath);
 $json= json_decode($response, true);
 $last = end($json); 
 $scoreID=$last['name'];
```

I also tried:

```
$todoPath = 'arcade/bonsai/gameInPlay/'.$userID.'/'.$gameID.'/'.$gamePlayID.'/scores/';
 $response =$fb->get($todoPath);
 $json= json_decode($response, true);
 $last = current(array_slice($json, -1));
 $scoreID=$last['name'];
```

neither of these work

Comment: Done a `var_dump($json)` to see what's really in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the pointer to the end of the object, and then get the key of the last item.

```
// move pointer to end
end($json);

// get the key
$key = key($json);
var_dump($key);
```

Let me know if this helps.